# Plotted data in Python and plotted data in QGIS is different

Tags: qgis, coordinates, plotting

I'm currently working with a raster dataset containing U.S. land cover data and a vector dataset containing building footprints within a specific state. When I attempt to plot two buildings that should be geographically close using Python, the points are displayed as expected. I am plotting Point() coordinates in QGIS and pixel coordinates in Python.

Here's the code I'm using in Python for reference:

```
import rasterio
from shapely.geometry import Point
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the EPSG codes for the source (building) and target (tree canopy) CRS
building_crs = 'EPSG:4326'
tree_canopy_crs = 'EPSG:5070'

# Define the single building coordinate in EPSG:4326
building_lon = -84.959634
building_lat = 32.421887

building_lon2 = -84.976805
building_lat2 = 32.264939

# Create a Shapely Point object for the building coordinate
building_point = Point(building_lon, building_lat)
building_point2 = Point(building_lon2, building_lat2)
# Define a function to reproject a point from one CRS to another
def reproject_point(point, src_crs, dst_crs):
    transformer = Proj(init=src_crs), Proj(init=dst_crs)
    lon, lat = transform(transformer[0], transformer[1], point.x, point.y)
    return Point(lon, lat)

# Reproject the building coordinate to EPSG:5070
reprojected_building = reproject_point(building_point, building_crs, tree_canopy_crs)

#SECOND BUILDING HERE.
#reprojected_building2 = Point(building_2[0], building_2[1])

reprojected_building2 = reproject_point( building_point2, building_crs, tree_canopy_crs)
print(reprojected_building, reprojected_building2)


# Open the TIFF file with tree canopy cover data
with rasterio.open('science_tcc_conus_2021_v2021-4.tif') as src:
    # Calculate the row and column indices of the surrounding area (100-meter radius)
    buffer_radius = 500   # in meters
    
    # Transform the reprojected building coordinate to the raster's CRS
    building_coord_in_raster_crs = src.index(reprojected_building.x, reprojected_building.y)
    
    building_coord_in_raster_crs2 = src.index(reprojected_building2.x,reprojected_building.y)
    print(building_coord_in_raster_crs, building_coord_in_raster_crs2)
    building_tot_min = [0] * 2
    building_tot_max = [0] * 2
    if building_coord_in_raster_crs[0] < building_coord_in_raster_crs2[0]:
        
        building_tot_min[0] = building_coord_in_raster_crs[0]
        building_tot_max[0] = building_coord_in_raster_crs2[0]
    else:
        building_tot_min[0] = building_coord_in_raster_crs2[0]
        building_tot_max[0] = building_coord_in_raster_crs[0]
    
    if building_coord_in_raster_crs[1] < building_coord_in_raster_crs2[1]:
        
        building_tot_min[1] = building_coord_in_raster_crs[1]
        building_tot_max[1] = building_coord_in_raster_crs2[1]
    else:
        building_tot_min[1] = building_coord_in_raster_crs2[1]
        building_tot_max[1] = building_coord_in_raster_crs[1]
    
    
    
    row_start = max(0, building_tot_min[0] -buffer_radius)
    row_end   = min(src.height, building_tot_max[0] + buffer_radius)
    col_start = max(0, building_tot_min[1] - buffer_radius)
    col_end   = min(src.width, building_tot_max[1] + buffer_radius)
    print(row_start)
    # Calculate the limits for the zoomed-in view
    xlim_min = max(0, building_tot_min[1] - buffer_radius)
    xlim_max = min(src.width, building_tot_max[1] + buffer_radius)
    ylim_min = max(0, building_tot_min[0] - buffer_radius)
    ylim_max = min(src.height, building_tot_max[0] + buffer_radius)
    
    print("Rows:", row_start, row_end, "Col:", col_start, col_end)
    print("Limits:", xlim_min, xlim_max, ylim_min, ylim_max)
    
    
    # Plot the zoomed-in view with building
    plt.figure()
    canopy_cover = src.read(1, window=((ylim_min, ylim_max), (xlim_min, xlim_max)))
    
    radius_search = 10
    trees_in_radius =[]
    trees_in_radius2 = []
    tree_coords = []
    tree_coords2 = [] 

    for row in range(row_start, row_end):
        for col in range(col_start, col_end):
            tree_point= Point(*src.xy(row, col))
            dot = row,col
            distance_to_building = calculate_distance(building_coord_in_raster_crs, dot)
            distance_to_building2 = calculate_distance(building_coord_in_raster_crs2, dot)

            if distance_to_building <= radius_search:
                
                canopy_cover_value = canopy_cover[row -row_start, col -col_start]
                if canopy_cover_value >= 25:
                    
                    tree_coord = row,col
                    tree_coords.append(tree_coord)
                    trees_in_radius.append((tree_point, canopy_cover_value))
            if distance_to_building2 <= radius_search:
                
                
                canopy_cover_value = canopy_cover[row -row_start, col -col_start]
                if canopy_cover_value >= 25:
                    trees_in_radius.append((tree_point, canopy_cover_value))
                    tree_coord = row,col
                    tree_coords2.append(tree_coord)
                
    tree_coords = get_ordered_coordinates(tree_coords,building_coord_in_raster_crs[0],building_coord_in_raster_crs[1])
    # Sort trees by distance to the building
    tree_coords2 = get_ordered_coordinates(tree_coords2, building_coord_in_raster_crs2[0], building_coord_in_raster_crs2[1])
    
#     trees_in_radius.sort(key=lambda x: x[0].distance(reprojected_building))
#     trees_in_radius2.sort(key=lambda x: x[0].distance(reprojected_building2))

    if tree_coords:
        nearest_tree = tree_coords[0]
        nearest_tree_point = nearest_tree
        print(f"Nearest Tree:  {nearest_tree_point}, Building: {building_coord_in_raster_crs}")
    else:
        print("No trees found within the 10-meter radius.")
    if tree_coords2:
        nearest_tree = tree_coords2[0]
        nearest_tree_point = nearest_tree
        print(f"Nearest Tree:  {nearest_tree_point}, Building:, {building_coord_in_raster_crs2}")
    else:
        print("No trees found within radius.")
        
    plt.imshow(canopy_cover, cmap='Greens', extent=[xlim_min, xlim_max, ylim_min, ylim_max])
    plt.colorbar()

    plt.plot(building_coord_in_raster_crs[1], building_coord_in_raster_crs[0], 'bo', markersize=8)
    plt.plot(building_coord_in_raster_crs2[1], building_coord_in_raster_crs2[0], 'mo', markersize=8)

    tree = tree_coords[0]
#     for trees in tree_coords:
#         plt.plot(trees[1], trees[0], 'ro', markersize=2)
        
#     for trees2 in tree_coords2:
#         plt.plot(trees2[1], trees2[0], 'ro', markersize=2)
    tree2 = tree_coords2[0]
    plt.plot(tree2[1],tree2[0], 'yo', markersize=2)
    plt.plot(tree[1], tree[0], 'yo', markersize=2)
    plt.xlim(xlim_min, xlim_max)
    plt.ylim(ylim_min, ylim_max)
    plt.legend()
    plt.title('Zoomed-In View with Reprojected Building')
    plt.xlabel('X-axis (Column Index)')
    plt.ylabel('Y-axis (Row Index)')
    plt.show()
```

I plotted reprojected_building and reprojected_building2 in QGIS.
Python:
[image]

QGIS:
[image]